# How can I color part of Slack incoming-webhook messages?

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I want to compose a python script which sends a color-formatted message to a configured slack channel. I managed to send sentences of plain texts to slack channels but I could not figure out how to confer part of the sentences colors that I want.

I used slackweb library in python as below

```
import slackweb
slack = slackweb.Slack(url = url_of_the_configured_channel)
string_to_send = "test TEST"
payload = {'text' : string_to_send}
slack.notify(text=string_to_send)
```

how can I, say, format **string_to_send** or **payload** so that the word 'test' appears  blue and 'TEST' appears red in the slack channel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you can do this at all?

Comment: Um... I heard it is possible, but i'm never sure

Comment: Well. I can't find this option on slack web or desktop client. And in bots API

Comment: You can abuse the backtick "code" quotes ("`") to make text red.

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately it is at the moment not possible to color text of a Slack message with the API. You can use different styles, e.g. bold and italic, but not colors. (See [Message Formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#message_formatting) in Slack documentation on how to use styles.)

You can use colors for your attachments. That will however result in a vertical color bar marker for the whole attachment, but not in colored text. (See [Attachment Parameters](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attachment_parameters) in Slack documentation on how to color your attachments.)

Here is an example on how to use colors for Slack attachments (taken from the Slack documentation):

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "New ticket from Andrea Lee - Ticket #1943: Can't rest my password - https://groove.hq/path/to/ticket/1943",
            "pretext": "New ticket from Andrea Lee",
            "title": "Ticket #1943: Can't reset my password",
            "title_link": "https://groove.hq/path/to/ticket/1943",
            "text": "Help! I tried to reset my password but nothing happened!",
            "color": "#7CD197"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why?  It seems like quite a simple thing

Comment: There is built-in "Create a text snippet" app that posts syntax-highlighted code as a selectable text so it should be possible somehow.

Answer (score 7):

What you can do (as an admittedly clumsy workaround until/unless Slack supports more than primitive formatting) is:

- Create your message as a small graphic image on your server
- upload the image's web address to the slack channel using the webhook
- the message is now displayed in channel

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) for this.

`.png` images allow for transparency, so you don't have to worry too much about background matching.

This is, of course, a terribly inefficient way to go about it, but it has the agreeable characteristic of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a color you need to add a attachment block to send message.

```
def slack_message(data):
        payload  = json.dumps(data)
        headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.request(url=slack_endpoint, method="post", headers=headers, data=payload)
```

You can send the request to slack_message in the below format:

```
slack_message(
{
   "attachments": [
      {
          "color": "#46567f",
          "blocks": [
           {
               "type": "section",
               "text": {
               "type": "mrkdwn",
               "text": f"Message"
               }
           }
         ]
       }
    ]
  }   
)
```

You can use this function to send slack message with color for a slack webhook generated for a channel.